# How to get a list of unmanaged dlls .NET assembly uses

Tags: pinvoke, dllimport

I have a third-party .NET library which fails to run with FileNotFound exception. Apparently it wants to use some unmanaged dll which it loads through DllImport.

How can I get a list of dlls, which are used in .NET dll?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227886/how-do-i-determine-the-dependencies-of-a-net-application

Comment: Thanks, Mitch - I'd like to mark this as an answer, but unfortunately this is only a comment.