# How to find all references in a solution (thus of all projects)?

Tags: visual-studio

We have a big solution with a lot of projects in it. Some projects reference the same DLL's and I need to replace one DLL. Is there a way to see which references are in the entire solution so I don't have to go over each project one by one?

I want to see the solution-wide references, not per-project. Is it possible?

Comment: How are you referencing the DLL? Is it in one place?

Comment: yes, it is. but the same file is referenced in 7 projects. The new dll has a different name (the version number is in the filename and we have to update the current version)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just to expand a little further on Juozas answer, you can use most modern Text editors to find/replace. For example in Notepad++ use `Find-in-Files` (Ctrl-Shift-F)

[image]

Notice I left the end quote off the search as sometimes the Reference will include additional info, eg

> Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=

Leaving off the end double quote may then give you false positive (as in my example it includes refs to `System.Data` and `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`

Answer (score 5):

You can try textual replace in .XXproj files to change the reference.

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio by itself doens´t provide any functionality to display or visualize project (assembly) references and dependencies.

For this i would recommened you to use [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/). It provides a Trial mode and it can analyze your assemblies and display the assembly dependencies.

Comment: That's why people don't like to switch from Java! Too much of don't, can't and not possible ;)

Comment: NDepend provides 3 way to analyze dependencies, code query, dependency graph and dependency matrix, more explanations here https://stackoverflow.com/a/308256/27194

Comment: @Choletski I wrote a node js script specifically to deal with this problem. I'll dig it up put it on github and reference it here