# display the video duration in sharepoint search core results web part

Tags: sharepoint-2010

does anyone of you know how can I display the duration
 of a video in search core results web part?

I don't see any fields to which I can map my Managed property in Central Admin.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes, they have answers, but are not the right anwsers. So, I cannot accept them. I accept them only if they are correct and helped me in sovling the issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406037/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies you say "problem solved!" but don't mark that as an answer

Comment: thanks for reminding me that one. I probably have forgotten to accept it.