# Tool to show assembly dependencies

Tags: .net, assemblies

I begun work in a new project with lots of assemblies in a single solution.
I am not familiar yet with the assembly dependencies and having a hard time figuring out which assembly depends on another.

Do you know any tools that are capable to show a dependency list or better a visual graph of it?

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[NDepend](https://ndepend.com) is the king when it comes to dependency graph analysis. NDepend is a commercial tool that proposes:

- a [dependency graph](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph)
- a [dependency matrix](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/dependency-structure-matrix-dsm),
- and also some [C# LINQ queries](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/cqlinq-features#Dependencies) can be edited (or generated) to browse dependencies.

See all details in this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/308256/27194) concerning a related question.

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. We already have NDepend in use for Code Metrix/code quality checks, but I haven't realized until now that it can create a code dependency graph also.
Have tested it and works like a charm. Its exactly what I needed !!!

Answer (score 17):

Here is some quick code to show case the **[Cecil Library](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil)** to do this:

- http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil

```
public static void PoC(IEnumerable<AssemblyDefinition> assemblies, TextWriter writer)
{
    Console.WriteLine("digraph Dependencies {");
    var loaded = assemblies
        .SelectMany(a => a.Modules.Cast<ModuleDefinition>())
        .SelectMany(m => m.AssemblyReferences.Cast<AssemblyNameReference>().Select(a => a.Name + ".dll"))
        .Distinct()
        .Select(dllname => {
               try { return AssemblyFactory.GetAssembly(dllname); }
               catch { return null; } })
        .Where(assembly => assembly != null)
        .ToList();

    loaded.ForEach(a => a.MainModule.FullLoad());

    loaded.ForEach(a =>
        {
            foreach (var r in a.MainModule.AssemblyReferences.Cast<AssemblyNameReference>())
                Console.WriteLine(@"""{0}"" -> ""{1}"";", r.Name, a.Name.Name);
        } );

    Console.WriteLine("}");
}
```

It generates a **[`dot` graph file](http://www.graphviz.org/)**. Running this on a fairly simple project results in:

[image]

Running it on a slightly less simple project returned this:

[image]

It may be advisable to filter out certain assemblies (`.StartsWith("System.")`?) and / or limit search depth etc.

Comment: awesome! (You should update the code to Cecil .9 to save you all the Cast<>()).

Comment: +1 for your image after "Running it on a slightly less simple project returned this".

Comment: @JbEvain: I'm behind on updates. Cecil serves me well many times but I don't get nearly enough time to write my tools. Thanks for the kind words (@others: JbE is the author of Cecil, the awesome library making this a breeze)

Comment: That looks cool, but as we already have NDepend in use in our company its the quicker and more effecient way for me, but thanks for your detailed explanations on this !

Comment: @SvenG: Huh/Stupified. You already have NDepend? I'm completely at a loss why the question got asked now.

Comment: We have bought it recently but I haven't been using it so far as I am not familiar with it and haven't had the time to investigate all its functionalities. We will receive a training on it in the future .. but have too many busy projects running atm.

Comment: @SvenG: well, fair enough, I suppose. I'd have thought that the name `NDepend` would be a kind of a giveaway :)