# FluentValidation - assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: manifest, .net-assembly, fluentvalidation

After adding the latest version of FluentValidation.MVC3 to a NopCommerce aplication i am receiving the following error,

```
 [Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'FluentValidation, 
 Version=3.2.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a82054b837897c66' or one 
 of its dependencies. The located   assembly's manifest definition does not 
  match the assembly reference. (Exception from  HRESULT: 0x80131040)
 ]
   Nop.Core.Plugins.PluginManager.Initialize() 
in C:\Nop 2.2 Source -Copy\just4fashion2.2source\Libraries\Nop.Core\
Plugins\PluginManager.cs:144
```

I think this is due to the project referencing an older version of the fluent validation dll
but im not sure how to fix this, is there a way to pinpoint the error further?

Any advice you can offer will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227886/how-do-i-determine-the-dependencies-of-a-net-application) helpful on how to track down dependencies in your application.  I think you're absolutely right that either your project or a dependency your project is taking references an older version of FluentValidation.

Another thought is if you add the dependency to FluentValidation.MVC3 via [NuGet](http://nuget.org/), NuGet tends to place [assembly binding redirects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/433ysdt1.aspx) in the web.config.  This will tell any assemblies with a hard dependency on an older version of an assembly to "redirect" to the latest version.

Comment: Unfortunately for some reason using the MVC5 NuGet package is not adding the redirect into web.config as I would have hoped. I don't even know why its trying to load version 3.x if I just installed 7.x. Weird?