# Visual Studio Crashes (File Not Found) When Creating New Android Project

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015

Trying to get started with app development (again).  Have Visual Studio 2015 Pro and installed and up-to-date Android SDK (in case it matters, here is [exactly what is installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnU2i.png)).

On creating a basic Android app from the Visual Studio templates, Visual Studio crashes.  Debugging the instance (with another Visual Studio instance) shows:

[image]

What's wrong?  How do I fix it?

---

Again, the problem is that *Visual Studio is crashing*.  This has nothing to do with debugging my application, which I haven't written yet.  It also has nothing to do with C# or Xamarin.

Comment: see the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729691/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-io-filenotfoundexception-occurred-in-unk

Comment: @guo No. See edit. Although that answer has superficially similar words, it is not at all related.