# What xunit binaries need to be added to source control?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, version-control, xunit

I want to use [xUnit](http://xunit.codeplex.com/) with my project for unit testing. Am using Visual Studio 2010 as my IDE. After downloading and extracting the xUnit1.9 release from their site, I see at least 25 different files. Some are .exe , .dll, .config, .xslt ...etc.

Can I assume that all I will need are "xunit.dll" and "xunit.gui.exe" ? The use case is that if I have someone else checkout the code from the repository, they should be able to start up the xUnit GUI and run the unit tests without any extra downloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just try it and see if it works :), or you can run Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see what dlls the xunit executable relies on.

For .NET files [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) is an open source option which does the same thing,

Comment: I've never heard of the tool before. It's a bit late for me now, so I'll check it out in the morning and report back with my results. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I can confirm that dependency walker doesn't work for me. Does it have some issues with .NET executables?

Comment: Should be ok - if not, looks like this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227886/how-do-i-determine-the-dependencies-of-a-net-application - I think by now though I would have just added the various DLLs one at a time until it stopped complaining about missing DLLs, then that would be my install set!

Comment: I need a free tool. The question you linked unfortunately points to a commercial product. On the good side, one of the comments led me to the ILSpy project which is just what I needed. I think I will approve your answer and edit it to include the tool. Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing these binaries in source control, you might be better off making a script to download the binaries and storing the script in source control.

Comment: That *is* an interesting idea, but not general enough for me. There can be cases where I (or my partner) do not have access to the internet and to depend on downloading the binaries wouldn't work in that case.

Comment: You don't have to run the download script every time you open your project.  You can run it only when you don't already have the stuff locally.  Presumably on first checkout from the repository, they're online.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to save storage space..?
Just use [nuget](http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2011/03/18/a-gentle-introduction-to-nuget.aspx) to keep track of the latest [xUnit](http://nuget.org/packages/xunit) release and forget about which files you should save...

If ~3MB is too expensive, you can skip `xunit.installer.exe`, and all GUI runners that you don't use (i.e, if you run .Net 4 on 64 bit machines, keep only `xunit.gui.clr4.exe`). This way you'll use only ~1MB.