# How can i find what is missing at run time that makes my application crash?

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on an application which is in C# and runs fine on my OS with Visual Studio installed.
If i take the executable to any other OSes,It crashes upon executing.
How can i know what exactly is missing so that i can solve the issue?
To be more precise on this case,I have used some Telerik components and i noticed there are already several Dlls pertaining to it next to the executable file.
I also installed Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2010 since there were reports in the project(in CR 2008),though i haven't used them so far.(I also tried installing

> SAP_Crystal_Reports_runtime_engine_for_.NET_Framework_4_32bit

And

> CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_1

On these systems which the application fails.But again no luck.

If I could know what exactly is missing I could know what I am dealing with and go straight forward to it and solve the issue

Comment: What error message did you get? Have you added any error handling to your program?

Comment: Catch the exception and display it.

Comment: I have placed an exception in my Program.cs ,But it seems it happens prior to executing the application itself(I mean first line of code ).I need to restart to write down the error.I'll be updating the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use the [Fusion log viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) to see assembly binding information on the target machine. Any assembly binding failures will be logged and you can see which assemblies are failing to load, and where the runtime is looking for them.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look through your list of references. Anything that isn't standard in the framework, set the property of the reference to copy the assembly to the build directory.]

Also, make sure you're building for the correct processor architecture in your project properties.

Comment: Thank you,I need to restart the system annd test it on my other OS.I'll report back if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check target machine's event log. There might be some dependencies missing. refer [Dependecies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227886/how-do-i-determine-the-dependencies-of-a-net-application). If it is crashing due to exception in application catch that in application exception event.

Comment: No i have placed a try-catch in Program.cs so that whenever an exception occurs i log it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [AssemblyResolve](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/310675/AppDomain-AssemblyResolve-Event-Tips) event for this

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)=>
    {
        string assemblyToResove = args.Name;
        //return Assembly.Load(....);
    };
```