# How to use PDFbox dll in QTP vbscript

Tags: dll, vbscript, qtp, pdfbox

I need to use PDFbox dll in QTP vbscript , initially  I tried to convert PDFbox jar to respective PDFbox dll with help of ikvmbin-7.2.4630.5, it was successfully so that i can use pdfbox.dll in c# and VB.NET similarly i need to use it with vbscript - QTP . Initially  tried to access the converted PDFbox.dll using DotNetFactory.CreateInstance

```
Set TestPDFDoc = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument","D:\\PDF\\PDF\\pdfbox-1.7.1.dll")
```

while executing it throws me but it throws me 
Type 'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument' not found in any loaded assembly

can anyone help me out
Thanks

Comment: do you actually need to escape backslashes in the dll path?

Comment: Yes i need to provide the path for DLL since its a custom DLL converted from jar to dll using IVKM

Comment: but do you need to escape the backslash, ie use `\\ ` instead of just `\ `? I don't know QTP, but in VBScript, you don't need to escape backslashes.

Comment: still it throws similar kind of error message :  Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\PDF\PDF\pdfbox-1.7.‌​1.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Try removing the `file://` part does `"D:\PDF\PDF\pdfbox-1.7.1.dll"` work?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to escape the backslashes, ie use `\\` instead of just `\` ? I don't know QTP, but in VBScript, you don't need to escape backslashes.

Ie try

```
Set TestPDFDoc = _
    DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument", _
                                 "D:\PDF\PDF\pdfbox-1.7.1.dll")
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the error occurs because one or more assemblies referenced by your .dll could not be found. Use a [.NET dependency viewer tool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/227886/113116) (for example, the open-source [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)) to determine the referenced assemblies and place them to the same folder as *pdfbox-1.7.1.dll*. I guess you need to place some of the IKVM.NET assemblies next to your .dll.

Comment: @Thanks helen for u r response ! do u have any idea how to place  IVKM.NET.core.dll next to our dll , I tried with Set TestPDFDoc = _
    DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument",  "D:\PDF\PDF\pdfbox-1.7.1.dll","D:\ikvmbin-7.2.4630.5\ikvm-7.2.4630.5\bin\IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll")
but it too fails so

Comment: @Ganeshja: Copy all the needed assemblies to the *D:\PDF\PDF* folder.