# Active Report closing VB6 Application

Tags: activereports

I am running a VB6 with ActiveReports Standard v2 sp3.  All of the sudden on one installation when creating a report the application shuts down.  Eventually the system wants to report the error to Microsoft on actrpt2.dll Version 2.0.0.1252.  If I copy the the clients database down on my machine it runs just fine.  We have tried it on several machines.  I have reinstalled the application.  Reregistered the DLL.  The client is using a terminal server running Server 2003.  It is simply a columnar report.

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information. What line of code does it occur on? What feature in the report causes this? Is it specific to data or the report layout? Do you have a crash dump & callstack? Ultimately, going through this troubleshooting process is probably best answered by ComponentOne's support team rather than asked as a question here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I would have suspected a dependency issue for actrpt2.dll. 
Check the dependency on your machine and do the same on the clients machine that this is failing.

For details on checking [dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227886/how-do-i-determine-the-dependencies-of-a-net-application)

May be it is best to contact Grape City folks their  [forum](http://www.datadynamics.com/forums/61/ShowForum.aspx) is pretty active.

Update: if you are using win32 version of AR (not the dot net version of active reports).
Try [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check dependancy