# Get all reference assemblies plus reference assemblies of the application reference assemblies and so on

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my ASP.NET application I am getting an error sometimes. When I refresh the page error will be gone. The error is,

```
Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I am thinking that some of my app assemblies reference this assembly. Is it possible to get all refrences recursively. I mean, I will get all reference assemblies of my application, all reference assemblies of my application's reference assemblies and so on.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227886/how-do-i-determine-the-dependencies-of-a-net-application

Comment: @Habib, thanks. but it does'nt solve my issue. I think ndepend is the correct tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this tool to find the DEpendencies

"NDepend"

[http://www.ndepend.com](http://www.ndepend.com/)

Comment: Once you add your applicatin in it, then it will provide a result with all the assessmeblies used in your application and its Dependecies information. See the sample report in below link.

http://www.ndepend.com/Res/NDependBig02.png

Try a Trial Version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a free [AssemblyInfo](http://assemblyinformation.codeplex.com/) tool to see the assembly dependency graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate your assemblies for references using a tool like [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)

Comment: I need assemblies references recursively