# WPF app loads WindowsFormsIntegration.dll - why?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm currently building a WPF app and have noticed that WindowsFormsIntegration.dll always gets loaded during startup.

Does anyone know *why* this dll is loaded, even though I'm not using any of the integration features between WinForms and WPF. (I am using WPF UI controls from Telerik, though, could that be the cause?)

I'm wondering if I can lower the startup time for the app by ensuring that no unecessary dll's are loaded.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227886/how-do-i-determine-the-dependencies-of-a-net-application

Comment: Is your project using the WindowsFormsHost?

Comment: @TimothyGroote: No, it does not.

Comment: @Mathias: To Reflector the dependencies is (of course) a good idea - I'll give it a try and see what turns up.