# Xamarin: Unable to compile android project. Could not load assembly System.web

Tags: android, xamarin, system.web

I have a problem compiling my project. It give me this error message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
>   File name: 'System.Web.dll'
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() (MightyMeeting)

I have not use system.web in my project. I left this project for couple of days then come back with it. but the compiler compile it.

Comment: Can you walk your assemblies and ensure there's not a reference to System.Web? System.Web is not supported in Xamarin.Android: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/assemblies/

You simply use a decompiler or use a tool found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227886/how-do-i-determine-the-dependencies-of-a-net-application

Comment: Actually after adding system.web manully, it's system.configuration..

Comment: Are you using any dll compiled for the .net framework? that seems a very probable cause, as @JonDouglas stated System.Web is not supported on Xamarin and any dll compiled with Xamarin will not have any reference to it.

Comment: I don't know but I would guess so.. I working with Thrift, may be I used the wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the following package fixed the error for my project.
[PCLCrypto 2.0.147](https://github.com/aarnott/pclcrypto/)