# Could not load file or assembly .... after installing with msi installler

Tags: dll, windows-installer, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to distribute an App but after starting it i always get the error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Die Datei oder Assembly "Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors,
Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" oder eine Abhängigkeit
davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
```

even though the .dll was in the correct folder before building the msi installer.

When running it in debug it works fine

It's a .Net 4.6.2 App and the problem comes from the Microsoft.Xaml.Behavior.WPF NuGet Version 1.1.39

Comment: [Dependency / Binding scan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51940598/129130). I don't do much .NET at the moment. Do you have a mix of release and debug files? NDepend or [Fuslogvw.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/e74a18c4(v=vs.71)) or whatever is popular these days to work out what is happening? [.NET binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/227937/129130).

Comment: which tool you're using to build msi installer?

Comment: No it's not a mix everything is from the release and i'm using the wix toolset. :)
But i already gave up, i skipped updating the nugets for this project and will rewrite it later with prism instead of mahapps metro (for this i need the xaml dll)